# Magento 2 find bundle items parent products

Tags: bundled-product, simple-product, magento2.1.5

I've simple product assign in bundle items of Bundle product.

Now I've simple product ID and I'm trying to find in which bundle product it's given in bundle items using following code but it returns an empty array.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$parent = $objectManager->create('Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type')->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());
var_dump($parent);
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/frxw2i

Comment: Not worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done in following way

```
public function getParentsId(){
        $products =  $this->_productCollection->create();
        $productcollection =$products->addAttributeToFilter([
                                ['attribute'=>'event_start_date','gt'=> date("Y/m/d") ]
                            ]);
        $parents = array();
        foreach ($productcollection as $product) {
            $parent = $this->findBundledProductsWithThisChildProduct($product->getId());
            array_push($parents, $parent);
        }
        return array_unique(array_reduce($parents, 'array_merge', array()));
    }


//Function by Alan Strom
function findBundledProductsWithThisChildProduct($id_to_find)
    {
        //grab all bundled products
        $bundles = array();
        $products = $this->_productCollection->create();
        $products = $products->addFieldToFilter('type_id','bundle');
        //loop over bundled products
        foreach($products as $product)
        {
            //get child product IDs
            $children_ids_by_option = $product
            ->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getChildrenIds($product->getId(),false); //second boolean "true" will return only
                                                       //required child products instead of all
            //flatten arrays (which are grouped by option)
            $ids = array();
            foreach($children_ids_by_option as $array)
            {
                $ids = array_merge($ids, $array);
            }

            //perform test and add to return value
            if(in_array($id_to_find, $ids))
            {
              $bundles[] = $product->getId();
            }
        }
        return $bundles;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Get Parent Product from Child Id.**

```
protected $_productloader;
protected $configurable;
protected $grouped;
protected $bundleSelection;

public function __construct(
    ...........................................................
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
    \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurable,
    \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped $grouped,
    \Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type $bundleSelection,
    ...........................................................
) {
    ...........................................................
    $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
    $this->configurable = $configurable;
    $this->grouped = $grouped;
    $this->bundleSelection = $bundleSelection;
    ...........................................................
}

...........................................................
...........................................................
...........................................................

public function getParentProductData($productData)
{
    $prdData = '';
    $parentProductId = $this->getParentProductId($productData->getEntityId());
    if ($parentProductId) {
        $prdData = $this->_productloader->create()->load($parentProductId);
    } else {
        $prdData = $this->_productloader->create()->load($productData->getEntityId());
    }
    // parent Product Data
    return $prdData;
}

public function getParentProductId($childId)
{
    $parent_id = 0;
    // configurable product
    $product = $this->configurable->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
    if (isset($product[0])) {
        $parent_id = $product[0];
        return $parent_id;
    }
    // group product
    $groupIds = $this->grouped->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
    if (isset($groupIds[0])) {
        $parent_id = $groupIds[0];
        return $parent_id;
    }
    // bundel product
    $budel_id = $this->bundleSelection->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
    if (isset($budel_id[0])) {
        $parent_id = $budel_id[0];
        return $parent_id;
    }
    return $parent_id;
}
```